# Did Sesame Street use to contain "Monster Time"?

Tags: muppets, sesame-street

I feel like when I was a child (not *that* many years ago), Sesame Street had something called "Monster Time" towards the beginning of the show. If it existed, it was dropped around 10 years ago, I think.

I tried Googling, but couldn't find any info on it.

Did this exist, or am I imagining it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Season 33 (2002) introduced the segment called Monster Time according to [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063951/reviews-18). It was [discontinued](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063951/reviews-23) the next year. There was a product line of kids' clothes referencing it:

[image]

Comment: Wow, somehow i only saw this 2.5 years later. My apologies. The timeline sounds about right. Good find!

Answer (score 0):

They had [Monster Clubhouse](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Monster_Clubhouse) and [Monsterpiece Theater](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Monsterpiece_Theater), but I don't ever remember Monster Time.

Could you be mixing up Mail Time from Monster Clubhouse?

Comment: It's possible, i guess...